# Why doesn't google block Youtube Downloaders

Tags: youtube, block, ads, policy, download-manager

So my question is if watching online videos benefit google (Youtube). why they do not block "Youtube downloaders" in google search.

Answer (score 0):

Google's CEO once stated in front of the House Judiciary Committee that "We don’t manually intervene on any particular search result."
I am also sure that manipulating search results to directly give themselves a financial advantage could put them at risk of being sued eventually..

Even if they didn't like it that people can download Youtube videos, it never directly hurt their business. If people do it because they have a slow internet connection, they would not be able to contantly stream their favorite videos anyway..